# Is it possible to build a code for sending `pseudo-filesystem` to other machine?

Tags: memory, cpu, sh, proc, info

I am on an effort to sending `pseudo-filesystem` to other machine.

In this case, I am using `/proc/cpuinfo` and `/proc/meminfo` as the pseudo-filesystem example.

I have two computer that can communicate each other in `ssh`.

Now, I am trying to build an ***.sh** code to secure copy some system file from other computer. The code was:

```
#INPUT
export MASTER=user@11.1.111.11
export HELPER=user@12.1.122.12


#Obtaining CPU and Memory Data
scp $MASTER:/proc/cpuinfo /master/.
scp $MASTER:/proc/meminfo /master/.
scp $HELPER:/proc/cpuinfo /helper/.
scp $HELPER:/proc/meminfo /helper/.
```

The idea is that I can run this script in any computer (either Master or Helper computer).

However, later on the copied files are blank and has no information inside.
I try to `sudo chmod` and `sudo chown` the `/proc/` folder but the system said permission denied. FYI, I do not activate `root` user and just using `sudo` all the time.

Can anybody guide me to some solutions please?

Additional info and improvisation:
The full code is in `jsfiddle`.
I am just trying to use collaboration option by `jsfiddle` though this code is not a JavaScript.
http://jsfiddle.net/santosasandy/sWYLL/#&togetherjs=hCO3VuPwO4

Comment: do a test to see if something simple (not using ssh) works. like `cp /proc/cpuinfo /tmp/master`. If that doesn't work, the scp version will never work. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @shellter thank you. Yes indeed the `ssh` works properly. I can do `scp` for other file without being asked a password. I am wondering why I can not copy `/proc/cpuinfo` and `/proc/meminfo`

Comment: @shellter Sorry for miss read your comment. I do your suggestion. I can copy it to `tmp` folder. The copied file has information (not blank). However I can not transfer it to other computer (Master to Helper or vice versa )

Comment: It the idea that /proc is a pseudo-filesystem is causing your problem. I think you'll have to `cp /proc/cpuinfo /tmp/master.cpuinfo ; scp /tmp/master.cpuinfo remote:/path/to/master.cpuinfo`. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you @shellter . The pseudo-filesystem makes me problem. I will think about the solution how to make a code for transferring that such a file

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `scp` first uses `stat` to determine the size of the file being transferred, and then transfers up to that number of bytes.  Because `/proc` is a pseudo-filesystem, and `/proc/cpuinfo` is a pseduo-file, `stat` reports its size as zero bytes.  Therefore, `scp` transfers nothing.

In contrast, `cp` appears to just read blocks from the file until it can read no more, so the zero size reported by `stat` is irrelevant.

To copy the file to another system it seems you'll have to first use `cp` to make a local copy, and then use `scp` to transfer over the network.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Eric. @shellter also suggest the same approach. However, do you have an idea on how to execute cp from another machine? Suppose that I am on Master and I want the code to do a `cp` in Helper machine from Helper `/proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: Highly probable theory about `stat`. Thanks for sharing. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cat` to read from the pseudo files, instead of trying to copy them. For example:

```
ssh $MASTER 'cat /proc/cpuinfo' > /master/cpuinfo
```

Comment: Briliant Idea. Thank you @chepner, I will try and let you know the result.